# How to wrap a command so that a script rather than its child appears as the executable?

Tags: bash, process

I wrapped my R script `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R` to limit memory usage: I renamed it to `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R_orig` and then created a bash script named `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R` with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Memory limited to 10G"
ulimit -Sv 10000000 #limit memory for 64-bit version
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R_orig "$@"
```

This is a huge improvement of my experience with that particular program, but I discovered that some parts of it actually use the executable name to determine package installation paths, and since the executable name is modified, they fail.

Is it possible to make my script `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R` to be seen as the executable by itself - so that for example `top` does not show a separate child process `R_orig`, but only the process `R`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that. By replacing the original `R` by something that outputs a string to standard output, you may well confuse applications that may parse its output.

Instead, create the wrapper script with a new name and leave the original `R` executable as it was.  Don't put this script in `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec` but someplace like `/usr/local/bin` (if it needs to be accessible by all users at all). This will additionally not confuse later package upgrades or uninstallation scripts.

You may alternatively define a shell function in your shell startup files:

```
myR () (
    echo "Memory limited to 10G"
    ulimit -Sv 10000000 #limit memory for 64-bit version
    exec /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R "$@"
)
```

Another obvious option would be to set the limit in your shell initialization scripts (`~/.bashrc` for `bash`). The limit will be carried over to any process started from the shell.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this possibility. The echo message is not a problem, it can be commented out. The reason I tried to do this is that other tools I use (jupyter R kernel) has that path hardcoded, so it looked as the easiest solution.

Comment: @Valentas note that when you set a limit with `ulimit`, it's set for the current shell and for all future processes started from that shell. A better place to set this limit may be in your shell startup files.

Comment: Thanks, your last comment may be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To hopefully answer your question, change the final line of your script to

```
exec -a "$0" /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R_orig "$@"
```

This will replace the current process (the shell running the script) with the R_orig program rather than run the R_orig as a child of the script. In addition it will pass the name of the program, the traditional first argument as the original name. Most programs which look up package installation will use this first name.

I do agree with @Kusalananda that it is a bad idea to output the "Memory limited to 10G" message. If you do want to do this then output it to stderr. This means your script should look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Memory limited to 10G" >&2
ulimit -Sv 10000000 #limit memory for 64-bit version
exec -a "$0" /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R_orig "$@"
```

Comment: Note that on Linux at least it will affect the output of `ps -f` (that shows the arg list) but not `ps` (which shows the process name which unless overridden is the first 15 bytes of the basename of the last command the process executed on Linux).